# Doctrine ORM - entity implements interface

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have following problem - in project, I have interface called TaggableInterface

```
interface TaggableInterface {
   public function addTag(TagInterface $tag);
   public function deleteTag(TagInterface $tag);
   public function getTags();
}
```

It is implemented by some entity classes.

Is there any good way in Doctrine that creates relations between those entites and tags? If Taggable wasn't interface but abstarct class, I would be able to solve it with entity inheritance..

Without Doctrine I would probably use Party/Accountability design pattern (http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood properly: you want to create mapping and implementation for interface without using abstract class and repeating code.

PHP have traits. You can create trait with common implementation of interface. From experience I know that you can also add doctrine annotations mapping to trait and everything will work well.

Create TaggableTrait. It behave like class or interface. It reside in namespace and will be loaded by your autoloader if you add it with `use`.

```
namespace My\Namespace;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait TaggableTrait 
{

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Some\Namespace\Entity\Tag")
    */
   protected $tags;

   public function addTag(TagInterface $tag)
   {
      $this->tags->add($tag);
   }

   public function removeTag(TagInterface $tag)
   {
      $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
   }

   public function deleteTag(TagInterface $tag)
   {
      $this->removeTag($tag);
   }

   public function getTags()
   {
      return $this->tags;
   }

}
```

And in your taggable entity:

```
namespace Some\Namespace\Entity;

use Some\Namespace\TaggableInterface;
use My\Namespace\TaggableTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TaggableEntity implements TaggableInterface
{
   use TaggableTrait;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   // rest of class code
}
```

Note that `use` inside class have different meaning. It add trait and have nothing to do with namespace importing.

You must always initialize `$tags` in your constructor, trait cannot do that.

That way you can create only unidirectional association. If you want more customization, remove mapping from trait and add it to class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, interesting idea using traits :)
Can you please show me some basic implementation of one of traits methods, e.g. addTag (I'm sure how to create the relationship)? Thanks

Comment: @Jadro007 I edited my answer. I also added `removeTag` because `removeXXX` is a doctrine/symfony convention. This will ensure that symfony won't get confused in situations like editing tags via form.

Comment: nice :) do I understand it correctly, that doctrine generates M:N relation entity for each entity that uses TaggableTrait?

Comment: Relations are not entities and are not represented as objects. It's managed by checking state of your `$tag` collection. Entity doesn't equal database table. Sometimes database table doesn't have entity and sometimes one entity is represented by many tables.

Comment: Sorry, I used bad terminology, I meant database table.

Comment: Yes, it is created when you run  `doctrine:schema:update`. Annotations from imported trait's code are treated equally with annotations from class's code.

Comment: thanks for your help, it gave me the right direction to create my own solution, described bellow. If you want, you can comment it if it's ok or if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I decided to use more complex solution that requires more code writing:

Each entity that implements Taggable, is connected one-to-one relationship to its taggable entity, that is many-to-many connected to TagEntity.

Class diagrams:

[image]

---

[image]

that creates this database:
[image]

---

[image]